# Keras custom softmax layer: Is it possible to have output neurons set to 0 in the output of a softmax layer based on zeros as data in an input layer?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, softmax

I have a neural network with 10 output neurons in the last layer using softmax activation. I also know exactly that based on the input values, certain neurons in the output layer shall have 0 values. So I have a special input layer of 10 neurons, each of them being either 0 or 1.

Would it be somehow possible to force let's say the output neuron no. 3 to have value = 0 if the input neuron no 3 is also 0?

```
action_input = Input(shape=(10,), name='action_input')
...

x = Dense(10,  kernel_initializer = RandomNormal(),bias_initializer = RandomNormal() )(x)
x = Activation('softmax')(x)
```

I know that there is a method via which I can mask out the results of the output layer OUTSIDE the neural network, and have all non zero related outputs reshaped (in order to have a total sum of 1). But I would like to solve this issue within the network and use it during the training of the network, too. Shall I use a custom layer for this?

Comment: So you want to make some of the output neurons zero and also rescale others to make them have a sum of one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end I came up with this code:

```
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
def mask_output2(x):
    inp, soft_out = x
    # add a very small value in order to avoid having 0 everywhere
    c = K.constant(0.0000001, dtype='float32', shape=(32, 13))
    y = soft_out + c

    y = Lambda(lambda x: K.switch(K.equal(x[0],0), x[1], K.zeros_like(x[1])))([inp, soft_out])
    y_sum =  K.sum(y, axis=-1)

    y_sum_corrected = Lambda(lambda x: K.switch(K.equal(x[0],0), K.ones_like(x[0]), x[0] ))([y_sum])

    y_sum_corrected = tf.divide(1,y_sum_corrected)

    y = tf.einsum('ij,i->ij', y, y_sum_corrected)
    return y
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Lambda` layer and `K.switch` to check for zero values in the input and mask them in the output:

```
from keras import backend as K

inp = Input((5,))
soft_out = Dense(5, activation='softmax')(inp)
out = Lambda(lambda x: K.switch(x[0], x[1], K.zeros_like(x[1])))([inp, soft_out])

model = Model(inp, out)

model.predict(np.array([[0, 3, 0, 2, 0]]))
# array([[0., 0.35963967, 0., 0.47805876, 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

However, as you can see the sum of outputs are no longer one. If you want the sum to be one, you can rescale the values:

```
def mask_output(x):
    inp, soft_out = x
    y = K.switch(inp, soft_out, K.zeros_like(inp))
    y /= K.sum(y, axis=-1)
    return y

# ...
out = Lambda(mask_output)([inp, soft_out])
```

Comment: Hi, I tried to make this work, but there is an error: in the line 'y /= K.sum(y, axis=-1)' since the y tensor is a shape of (batch_size,5) and the K.sum returns a shape of (5), and python reports an error here right the first run. On top of that the case is a bit more complicated since we have to avoid dividing by zero, in case the K.sum returns zero, we not only need to correct it to 1 but we have to set somehow the inp row data to something different from zero as well in order to reshape them at the end and to have a sum of outputs equal to one. Could you please help?

Comment: @user898160 It works on my machine. The result of sum will be broadcasted. What error do you get? Edit your question and add the error you get. As for the sum of zero, it only happens when the input is all zero, otherwise it never happens since the output of Softmax is not zero at all.